# Compiling bootstrap less shows errors/warnings

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less, netbeans-8

I've a large project using Bootstrap3 CSS Framework. We use Netbeans IDE which supports less compile on save. Netbeans is using the syntax

Using lessc Version 2.4.0 on a Ubuntu machine installed via npm.

```
$ lessc less/compiled.less css/compiled.css
```

Full output:

```
"/usr/local/bin/lessc" "--source-map" "--source-map- rootpath=../themes/bodensee/less" "--source-map-url=compiled.css.map" "/usr/local/vufind2/themes/bodensee/less/compiled.less" "/usr/local/vufind2/css/compiled.css"
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .btn-xs' has no matches
 extend ' .btn-sm' has no matches
extend ' .btn-lg' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .img-responsive' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
extend ' .img-responsive' has no matches
extend ' .clearfix' has no matches
Done.
```

I dont't know what kind of errors they are., but I find them annoying. When I try using another syntax

```
$ lessc less/compiled.less > css/compiled.css
```

it suddenly works without these messages. Netbeans offers no way to change the syntax. Anybody knows a solution?

Comment: https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-less2css/pull/106 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450144/bootstrap-bootswatch-theme-with-less-how-to-compile

Comment: I already tried this. This thread is more about the compress error in the last line. I do not get this error. Updating less-plugin-clean-css does not help.

Comment: In you second link, it seems that the > sign is correct and Netbeans implemented it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also see: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2449

Less seems to threw an error when the code contains `@media` declaration in the main scope. As far i understand this error (warning) does not influence the extending itself.

You could safely run less with the `--silent` option to suppress this warning.

Comment: This is the same answer that @michelle-glauser gave, but she also informed us of where to insert the argument into django settings.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with a Django app, and adding this to my settings file fixed the problem:

```
PIPELINE_LESS_ARGUMENTS = '-s'
```